# PDO Updating Database on Page load

Tags: php, pdo

I am building a cms using php,pdo in oop format. On various pages i call functions to update the database on page load in order to keep the database up to date in real time ( Entire site is User content driven things need to be updated and fixed in database outside of forms so i update database on page load for certain things ).

Example

```
$expiredMatches = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM matches WHERE match_date <= $now AND status = 0");
```

so the above fetches all matches that need to have their status set to 2 ( expired ) 
I then loop through each and process point refunds if they are necessary

```
foreach ($expiredMatches as $em) {
    // Check to see if points were used
         // If ^ Yes then refund users 
}
```

This may be a dumb question but i have not thought about it much until now. My question is this.

If the page is loaded by multiple users at the same time will the refunded users receive multiple refunds?

Comment: Look up locking and transactions for your DBMS. It really depends on your environment so you should add which Database and storage engine you are using.

Comment: your code is wrong by the way, you cant pass query string to a fetch function

Comment: I have defined a class with functions to allow me to pass parameters to shorten the length of a prepared statement. I just did not list that.

Answer (score 0):

Link to PDO transactions manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

> "any work carried out in a transaction, even if it
>   is carried out in stages, is guaranteed to be applied to the database
>   safely, and without interference from other connections, when it is
>   committed."

Comment: With the transaction do i place the everything within the transaction or only the db update/queries. By this i mean do i include all of the if statements and foreach statements within the transaction.

Comment: you should include everything that needs to be included in the transaction, i.e. anything directly involved in the query. Since your example runs a query and then operates upon the results, you should be able to have the `foreach` outside the `transaction`. If, however, you wanted the option of 'rolling back' if an error occurred during the `foreach` then you should consider putting that inside the `transaction` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the help. One last question i was reading through this
http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=83
and it appears that once the transaction is commit-ed by user1 then user2 data will be saved. I am trying to prevent data being overwritten by another user. Once a match is set to expired and a user is refunded they should not receive another refund because someone else loaded the page at the same time of another. Am i misunderstanding this or will things be fine as long as i use a transaction?

Comment: if you put all the changes inside the transaction you will be fine. So you will likely need to put you `foreach` inside the transaction as well (I should have seen that earlier). Whatever is inside the transaction is supposed to be safe from other users. On the page you linked to, refer to the table in part "3. Examples of Simple Locking" for a good example of the intended purpose of transactions.